Azure APIM missing subscription key error on single api call of larger set
I have a set of API calls that go through Azure APIM to reach our backend. All but one of the calls function as they should, given that the subscription key is included. However the function below, despite having the subscription key assigned in the header section, always results in a 401: access denied, missing subscription key. To keep the post neat, I will exclude the extra types because they will quickly clutter the post, and I don't believe they are the cause.
export const webApiConfig: WebApiConfig = {
  endpointUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBAPI_ENDPOINT as string,
  subscriptionKey: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBAPI_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY as string,
};

export const trainProjectAsync = async (projectName: string): Promise<NluTrainingState> => {
  try {
    // Build the request url and config
    const url: string = `${webApiConfig.endpointUrl}/Nlu/${projectName}/Train`;
    const token = await getToken();
    const requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": webApiConfig.subscriptionKey,
      },
      signal: new AbortController().signal,
    };

    // Perform the POST request
    const response = await axios.post<NluTrainingState>(url, requestConfig);

    return response.data satisfies NluTrainingState;
  } catch (error) {
    // check whether the error is an axios error or a stock error.
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      throw new Error(`API call axios malfunction code: ${error.code} ${JSON.stringify(error.response)}`);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`API call stock malfunction, reason: ${error}`);
    }
  }
};

This is the function that it's supposed to hit via the APIM (and testing it via postman or in swagger shows that this function works as it should). But when the API is locally hosted without API Gateway inbetween, the frontend API call will result in a 401 result as well.
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("{projectName}/Train")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<NluTrainingStateDto>> TrainAsync(string projectName)
{
    try
    {
        // Launch a training job.
        NluTrainingStateDto result = await _nluService.TrainAsync(projectName);

        // Return the correct status based on whether the request was a success.
        if (result != null)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceAccessException serviceEx)
    {
        // TODO: add logging
        IError error = _errorFactory.CreateError(ErrorCode.ControllerNotServiced, _exceptionResourceManager.GetString("ConnectionNotServicedExc")!);

        ControllerNotServicedException _controllerEx = new(error, serviceEx);

        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, $"Internal Server Error: {_controllerEx.Message}");
    }
}

I've tried to make the request with four different methods, POST, PATCH, PUT and GET. All of them fail except for GET, but I believe it breaks convention to use GET for this request and am saving this as a last resort. I should note that this particular function used to work as a POST request before
EDIT: The APIM is created via OpenAPI specification through swagger url.

This may come across as a bit odd, as this solution has failed me before.
I had the same problem today because I forgot to add a body to the post request. This time it was resolved by simply changing axios.post(url, config) to axios.post(url, {}, config).
I am also aware that my OPs may sometimes be missing key information, that I thought was unimportant. I will try to improve on that.


This is the function that it's supposed to hit via the APIM (and testing it via postman or in swagger shows that this function works as it should). But when the API is locally hosted without API Gateway in between, the frontend API call will result in a 401 result as well

Please verify if you are passing correct JWT token while calling from frontend as well as from APIM. I am using below code to generate JWT token and using the same while making the requests.
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace JwtTokenGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = GenerateJwtToken();
            Console.WriteLine($"Generated JWT Token: {token}");
        }

        static string GenerateJwtToken()
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<Key>"));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "Test Claim"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "<https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/>",
                audience: "<audience value>",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: credentials);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}


I have the given code in program.cs file.

using _78711442;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddScoped<INluService, NluService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


You can directly test it in APIM by adding the bearer token in the request header.





Please check if the variables declared in .env is being populated correctly in your code to resolve access denied, missing subscription key  error and also .env should be created in the root folder.


REACT_APP_WEBAPI_ENDPOINT=<endpoint>

REACT_APP_WEBAPI_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY=<subscription key>


You can also pass the subscription key directly in the code itself.

import axios from 'axios';

export const webApiConfig = {
    endpointUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBAPI_ENDPOINT,
    subscriptionKey: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBAPI_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
};

export const trainProjectAsync = async (projectName) => {
    try {
        const url = `${webApiConfig.endpointUrl}/WeatherForecast/${projectName}/Train`;
        const requestConfig = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer eyJhbGciOi******-FBSYNXiI`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": webApiConfig.subscriptionKey,
            },
        };
        const response = await axios.post(url, {}, requestConfig);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            throw new Error(`API call axios malfunction code: ${error.code} ${JSON.stringify(error.response)}`);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`API call stock malfunction, reason: ${error}`);
        }
    }
};

I am able to get the expected response.


I appreciate your answer, but my underlying issue stems from the fact that the correct bearer token formatted as Bearer token and the correct subscription key are both present in the headers of the axios.post() request. Even though both are present, it still results in a 401 access denied due to missing subscription token.

Have you tried to add the subscription key directly in the request header instead of using a dynamic variable? Even I was getting the same error even I moved .env file to the root directory

I could try that, but it wouldn't qualify as an acceptable solution because the subscription key is a secret that we inject as env var via pipeline at build time. I also want to note that React Msal (from microsoft) is responsible for generating my bearer tokens.

You should have mentioned these details in the OP

I agree, in hindsight. I didn't think the method of acquisition for the bearer token would matter for this issue.
On a positive note, I'd like to share that the solution to the problem was to add an empty {} as body for the post request like so axios.post(url, {}, config). I have to be honest here and note that I tried this before and it didn't work as expected.

@RK I see headers are added in requestConfig and you are getting subscription related issue thats means clearly subscription key is not being passed correctly while making the request then how by changing (url, {}, config) worked for you?
